# Connect to SharePoint in Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2013

We are encountering an issue with debugging a SharePoint app. This issue has occurred suddenly, and after some extensive research, haven’t found the solution. When clicking Start (or F5), as per usual SharePoint apps, it prompts with a “Connect to SharePoint screen for inputting username and password, however, we are now getting a Script error on that page and the screen doesn’t load at all. This causes us not to be able to authenticate, thus the app cannot load for testing.

[image: Screenshot of Issue]

Any help on this would be appreciated, as this has happened on two separate instances of VS now.

Comment: What happens if you try to open the actual page outside of Visual Studio, in a browser ? Hit the browsers F12 (Developers mode) and relad the page, what does it say ?

Comment: I can get to this page perfectly fine in the browser - no errors at all. It it simply occuring from VS

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/61795)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to simply upgrade Internet Explorer. I could then see the login screens as expected.